# slideToggle Jump

Tags: jquery

I have seen many posts about the issue with jQuery and the slide toggle jump issue but I am new to this code and do not understand fully what I need to do to fix it. I am attempting to have several button and when button1 is clicked it opens but then when another button (button2) is clicked the Button1 closes and Button2 opens. I have this part working but I am still suffering from the jumping issue. Here is my code:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $('div[name|="newboxes"]').each(function(index) {
   if ($(this).attr("id") == divId) {
       $(this).slideToggle(1500, "easeInOutCirc") 
   } else {
       $(this).slideUp(500, "easeInOutCirc");
   }
   });
function toggleByClass(className) {
     $("."+className).toggle();
}
}
```

Any advice would be very helpful and very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: probably some css margin issues. can you post your html code too

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle example?

Comment: Here is a link to the page I have been working on. The HTML is probably really messy, and I apologize for that.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2600525/Overflow/home.html
@j08691

Answer (score 0):

The slide Toggle() API of J Query have problem of jumping .
In my issue i tried to slide the div in which data is rendering at run time so face the problem of jumping .

I end with following soution :

`$("#divId").animate({"margin-top" : "toggle"});` // to slide down but it opens div smoothly as slide Toggle API
`$("#divId").animate({"height" :"toggle"}) ;` //to slide up